# Can I block a nested swf to make http calls?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For instance: I have a swf, lets say "A", that loads another swf, "B".
Can I block on B any kind of communication with internet?

```
 A loads B --- X --- internet
 ^                      ^
 |______________________|
```

Thank you!!!
G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.  Internet access is not something you can block security-wise.